# Rerndering Partial View with Data on RowEdit in Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have a telerik grid. I have added Edit button to edit data for each row. The edit is type of pop up. On clicking edit button, i want to call a controller method of type Get which returns me a partial view that includes some data. The view should bind the data it gets from the controller function. Is it possible? I know i can do this with view returning JSON but with that i have manually bind all the controls. Like i have to assigning values to tax boxes and so on. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: I think you want something like this: http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/Dinners but using telerik grid; here when you click edit the content of the popup will load via ajax, and no client side binding required